# Symfony 2 getters and setters

Tags: symfony

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid using getters and setters for a Symfony 2 entity. Although the php app/console doctrine:generate:entities is very helpful, line codes seem to increase a lot for an entity with a lot of fields

Comment: Doctrine won't work with public properties properly since it can't make lazy-loading work on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Code won't work properly if  skip getters and setters.
Especially if you have mapping with different Entities.

Doctrine uses getters nad setters to populate various members fields during storing and fetching of information

Its very bad practice to use public for every property in Entity.
and also you will end  up wasting lot of time in changing the property to public as doctinr uses proted when it autogenerate the code

Answer (score 2):

You can define the visibility of your properties from **protected** or **private** to **public** so you now have access to them in this way:

```php
// on entity
public $someProp;

// On your code
$someEntity->someProp = someValue;
```

**This is not a good OOP practice and should be avoided**, getters and setters are the way to go if you want clean and secure code.